# SQL Server Case Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query and trying to see if the way its written i can have best possible performance

```
UPDATE UserSession 
SET
    PauseSpan = CASE State WHEN 9 THEN PauseSpan + @SPAN ELSE PauseSpan END, 
    PauseSpanTotal = CASE State WHEN 9 THEN PauseSpanTotal + @SPAN ELSE PauseSpanTotal END,
    PendSpan = CASE State WHEN 5 THEN PendSpan + @SPAN ELSE PendSpan END, 
    PendSpanTotal = CASE State WHEN 5 THEN PendSpanTotal + @SPAN ELSE PendSpanTotal END
WHERE State = 9 OR State = 5
```

As you can see the `WHERE` statement will cause two types of records to be filtered with state 9 and 5.

Since some of the `CASE` statements will not be satisfied the default ELSE behavior will default the result to NULL and the statement will fail as the columns in question are not nullable.

So you can see that I have added ELSE to end of each statement and pass the column name to it, as I understand this will simply cause the column to keep its default value in case CASE won't match.

The question is will this affect performance as the default values will be re-written to each column?

Comment: schema, input, output

Comment: "Performance" has no real definition. If you are really concerned, you will compare execution plan of this approach with at least one other obvious approach (2 update statements - 1 for each State) to determine if there is an improvement. If you have a trigger on this table, you might think very differently about your current approach.

Comment: ok putting performance aside is there extra work SQL server will need to do with the ELSE default column value or will this not require any extra operation ?

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this using `IN` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE UserSession 
    SET PauseSpan = (CASE State WHEN 9 THEN PauseSpan + @SPAN ELSE PauseSpan END) 
        PauseSpanTotal = (CASE State WHEN 9 THEN PauseSpanTotal + @SPAN ELSE PauseSpanTotal END),
        PendSpan = (CASE State WHEN 5 THEN PendSpan + @SPAN ELSE PendSpan END), 
        PendSpanTotal = (CASE State WHEN 5 THEN PendSpanTotal + @SPAN ELSE PendSpanTotal END)
WHERE State IN (5, 9);
```

This doesn't affect performance.  The only thing you can do from a performance perspective is add an index on `(State)`.  However, if many rows have states `5` and `9`, this won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Because there is no effective difference? Perhaps because this is really more of a comment?

Comment: @SMor . . . Not exactly.  An index could help, but that depends on the nature of the data.  It probably won't, but it could.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt SQL Server would waste time by overriding a value with the same value, but there is an easy way to find this out. Run something like this:

```
update UserSession
set PauseSpan = PauseSpan;
```

and now take a look at how many rows are affected. If this number is 0, then the update will not override a value with itself. If it's the same number as the number of records, then update overrides the value with itself

EDIT

Since all records are affected, this affects performance, but one should not worry about it until performance becomes an issue.